# Indexing using iloc

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, kaggle

Going through a kaggle tutorial the now, while I get the basic idea of what it does, from looking at the output and reading up the documentation, I think I need confirmation of what is going on here:

```
predictors = ["Pclass", "Sex", "Age", "SibSp", "Parch", "Fare", "Embarked"]
kf = KFold(titanic.shape[0], n_folds=3, random_state=1)

predictions = []

for train, test in kf:
     train_predictors = (titanic[predictors].iloc[train,:])
```

My main issue here is the last line with the `iloc` function. The rest is just for context. It just splits the training data up?

Comment: You could've looked at the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-position) and printed out `train` no?

Comment: @EdChum yeah I am looking at docs, and honestly I printed out train_predictors to see how that was changed. If I print train on its own before and after that line, its the same, since that wasn't changed outside the train_predictors variable no?

Comment: your indentation is off, shouldn't `train_predictors = (titanic[predictors].iloc[train,:])` be indented?

Comment: Yeah, it is in my code. I forgot to do it when putting it on here. Wasn't a straight copy paste since I have a lot of commenting.

Answer (score 2):

`.iloc[]` is the primary method to access `row` and `column` index of `pandas` `DataFrames` (or `Series`, in this case `index` only). It is quite well explained [in the Indexing docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/indexing.html#selection-by-position).

In this specific case, from the `scikit-learn` [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#cross-validation-iterators):

> `KFold` divides all the samples in k groups of samples, called folds
>   (if k = n, this is equivalent to the Leave One Out strategy), of equal
>   sizes (if possible). The prediction function is learned using k - 1
>   folds, and the fold left out is used for test. Example of 2-fold
>   cross-validation on a dataset with 4 samples:
>
> ```
> import numpy as np
> from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold
>
> kf = KFold(4, n_folds=2)
> for train, test in kf:
>     print("%s %s" % (train, test)) 
> [2 3] [0 1] [0 1] [2 3]
> ```

In other words, `KFold` picks the `index` positions, these are used in the `for` loop over `kf` and passed to `.iloc` so that is selects the appropriate `row index` (and all `columns`) from the `titanic[predictors]` `DataFrame` containing the training set.

Comment: are these the same `newDf = df.iloc[:-1]` and `newDf = df[:-1]`?

Comment: iloc is specifically for integer indexing as opposed to indexing by label.

Comment: Did this answer your question after all?

Comment: yes that helps me a lot - do you know of any good pandas tutorials - specifically the basics around the dataframe object? (I've upped your answer - although not for me to mark it as correct though as I'm not the original questioner)

Comment: Hi, thanks. It really pay to carefully read through the pandas docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/. There's also Wes McKinney's (original pandas author) book - here's the github repo with related notebooks: https://github.com/wesm/pydata-book.

Comment: oh yeah - very nice: I'll export some of those notebook and play - cheers. I'm still struggling with the basics of DataFrames